# How to post checkbox items to the next page?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP. I have a doubt about posting values of checkbox items to another page as an array. Can anyone tell me a solution for this.

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/> Politics<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/> Movies<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/> World<br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
 </form>
```

and the php code is

```
    <?php 
     $checked = $_GET['options'];
     for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++)
    {
        echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You lack the "action" attribute of form (unless HTML form and PHP script share the same .php file). If you want it in another page, separate your code.

Comment: If you want to POST values you should change the method to 'POST', also add an action attribute.

Comment: It seems you are using code provided by someone else, like a person or tutorial. I'm going that you're still learning, so I suggest you keep researching on tutorial sites, read some books and practice. There is no question here.

Comment: which value i have to echo in the action page?

Comment: @SyamSree check the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add action attribute in your form tag for redirecting on   another page then post your following code on that page.

```
<?php
     $checked = $_GET['options'];
      for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++)
       {
       echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] ;
       } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Before doing php operation, check whether form is submitted and `options[]` value is set. If it is then iterate through array as you have `[]` as name.

Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit'] !== null) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['options'])) {
        $options = $_REQUEST['options'];
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) {
            $str .= "Selected " . $options[$i] . "<br/>";
        }
        echo $str;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Testing
        </title>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" name="form">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/>
            Politics
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/>
            Movies
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/>
            World
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
        </form>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

the action/answer can also be on different page.(as i have done)

**Index Page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Testing
        </title>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="display.php">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/>
            Politics
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/>
            Movies
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/>
            World
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
        </form>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Display Page:**

```html
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit'] !== null) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['options'])) {
        $options = $_REQUEST['options'];
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) {
            $str .= "Selected " . $options[$i] . "<br/>";
        }
        echo $str;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form method="post">//changed get to post
      <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/> Politics<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/> Movies<br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/> World<br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
     </form> 

      <?php 
     $checked = $_POST['options'];//changed get to post
     for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++)
    {
    echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```